# Play hold music on Twilio Conference after it was started

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I got two people in the same conference room #1, then I moved only one person to another conference #2, but kept the conference room #1 alive.

I was expecting that Twilio plays the hold music for the person left alone in the conference #1 until the other person goes back from #2 to #1, but since the conference was already started, there was only silence.

How can I make Twilio play the hold music when someone is left alone in the conference room, even though the conference was already started?

Thanks,

**Update**

I saw the new participant hold feature, tried to use it instead but no luck as well. See here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/368

**Solved**

I found a participant hold feature which does exactly what I want, without having to move an user to another conference. It had a bug (per my update above), but it was fixed. So the solution would be to update the participant with `Hold => true`:

```
$this->client
->conferences($conferenceSid)
->participants($memberCallSid)
->update(['Hold' => 'true']);
```

Moving him to a new conference as suggested here should solve this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue a while back and was suggested by the twilio support team to transfer the remaining caller to a new empty conference room and this will trigger the hold music. They said you can't play hold music again after the conference room has started.

Comment: They actually had a bug, and the code I wrote on my Github issue now works. Your suggestion should also work as a workaround though..

Answer (score 3):

Besides updating the participant by setting the `Hold` attribute to true, you need to update the `HoldUrl` attribute.

According to the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#optional-parameters),

> The 'HoldUrl' attribute lets you specify a URL for music that plays
> when a participant is held. The URL may be an MP3, a WAV or a TwiML
> document that uses Play, Say or Redirect.

Your code should look like below :

```
$this->client
     ->conferences($conferenceSid)
     ->participants($memberCallSid)
     ->update(
         [
             'Hold' => 'true', 
             'HoldUrl' => 'some url to mp3 file, wav file or twiml'
         ]
     );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll test. But they said on another page that they have a default hold url, so not sure.. but I'll test anyway.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug.. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/368